# In auth gaurd angular 17 always showing toastr error message

Tags: angular, auth-guard, ngx-toastr

**Problem solved** 
Issue for SSR (server site rendering). In angular 17 have an option server site rendering while creating project. Server site create error and showing it in HTML but don't remove it.
To solve I updated the angular.json file

```
...
"server": "src/main.server.ts",
"prerender": true,
"ssr": {
"entry": "server.ts"
}
...
```

to

```
...
"server": "src/main.ts"
...
```

---

**Problem** 
I'm using angular 17 and using toastr to show informational messages also using auth guard.

```
export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {

  const accountService = inject(AccountService);
  const toastr = inject(ToastrService);

  return accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
    map(user => {
      if(user){
        console.log("Calling me valid user",user);
        return true;
      }
      else{
        console.log("Calling me invalid user",user);
        toastr.error('you shall not pass!');
        return false;
      }
    })
  )
};
```

routing:

```
{
    path:'',
    runGuardsAndResolvers : 'always',
    canActivate : [authGuard],
    children : [
      {path:'members',component:MemberListComponent},
      {path:'members/:id',component:MemberDetailComponent},
      {path:'lists',component:ListsComponent},
      {path:'messages',component:MessagesComponent},
    ]
  },
```

after logging when i reload page , in my vscode terminal showing
`console.log("Calling me invalid user",user);` output

and browser console showing
`console.log("Calling me valid user",user);` output

and again in browser showing toastr error message
`toastr.error('you shall not pass!');`

Comment: please provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: stackblitz please :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Mestu-Paul/DatingApp

just look at Client folder, mainly it is angular project

Comment: This looks like an SSR issue. The toast is likely generated server side and set to the client via HTML